# Lebesgue point of density on $[0,1]$ and Dynkin's theorem

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The problem defines a density point $x\in[0,1]$ for a Borel set $A\subset [0,1]$ if $$ \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\mu([x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon]\cap A)}{2\varepsilon}=1.$$Denote all the density point of $A$ to be $A^*$. The problem asks 
to show $$A^*\text{ is Borel}, \mu(A\,\Delta\, A^*)=0, \forall \text{Borel } A\subset[0,1]$$
where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure and $\Delta$ means symmetric difference.

The point here is that the professor asks to use Dynkin's $\pi-\lambda$ theorem to prove and he note that interval $I$ would have $\mu(I\,\Delta\, I^*)=0$.

I manage to show $A^*$ is Borel but do not know how to show the second part.  I let $\pi$ system be all the intervals in $[0,1]$   and the $\lambda$ system to be $S=\{A\text{ is Borel}:\mu(A\,\Delta\, A^*)=0\}$. I got trouble in checking that if $A\in S$ then $A^c\in S$ and if $A_1,\ldots,A_n,\ldots\in S$, $\bigcup A_n\in S$.

Indeed, I am not sure that whether Dynkin's theorem could be applied here or make the problem easier. Or we still need to go through the proof using Vitali covering lemma.

Answer (score -1):

Let $C$ be the the collection of intervals. We know that for any $I \in C$ the Theorem holds.

Use that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $C$ (the Borel sets) coinsides with the Dynkin class generated by $C$.

Comment: This does not really help. The problem is that it is hard (impossible?) to show (without using Lebesgue's differentiation theorem) that the class of "good sets" (i.e. those for which $\mu(A \Delta A^\ast) = 0$) form a Dynkin class.

Comment: Use the regularity of Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Could you please give some more details? I know what regularity of the Lebesgue measure is, but I do not see how this would imply the claim.

Comment: Indeed, I even got trouble in checking open and closed set are in the Dynkin class. For open set, its point density set is as large as the open set and is contained in the closure of the open set but then how to show the difference between the open set and the density point set has measure 0. The boundary of the open set might not be zero  so I can not proceed.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I was a bit to quick, I don't see how to do it without a covering lemma. My idea was the following. If $C$ is the class of sets $A$ with density 1 at $x$ for almost all $x \in A$ and density 0 for almost all $x$ in the complement, then $[0,1] \in C$ is obvious. Also, if $A, B \in C$ and $B \subset A$, then clearly $B - A \in C$. What seems difficult is to prove that if $A_n$ is an increasing sequence of sets in $C$ then $\cup_n A_n \in C$. One can also try to work with the class of sets $A$ with density 1 in almost all points in $A$. Then the second property that is difficult.

Comment: @TomasPersson, Any idea in showing open and closed sets belongs to the Dynkin class?

Comment: No, no idea unfortunately. But observe the following: If $C$ is the class I defined in my previous comment, then $C$ is closed under finite intersections: If $A,B \in C$, then $A \cap B \in C$. So if one can show that $\cup A_n \in C$ whenever $A_n$ is an increasing sequence in $C$, then it follows that $C$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and it is not necessary to use Dynkin's theorem. This is an indication that maybe it is not so easy.

Comment: How does the Dynkin class generated by $C$ relate to the density points?

Comment: I have used $C$ for two different things above. Sorry! If $C$ is the class of intervals then the Dynkin class generated by $C$ is the Borel sets, and the density points are known by the Theorem of Lebesgue. Was this you question?

Comment: Well, no. You still have to show that the elements of the generated Dynkin class satisfy the same density condition as the intervals - this is equivalent to the OP's question. What you have written is correct, but it doesn't answer the question. To emphasise, just because something is true for the intervals does not make it automatically true for the generated Dynkin class. (Otherwise if something was true for the intervals it would automatically be true for the Borel sets.)

Comment: The idea was to show that the class of Borel sets satisfying the density theorem is a Dynkin class (this can be showed easily with a covering lemma). Since the intervals satisfy the density theorem, it follows that the dynkin class generated by them is contained in the class of sets satisfying the density theorem.